# Entanglement across a bi-partition of a many particle system

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Alice and Bob each have two qubits labelled $A', A$ and $B, B'$ respectively. The density operator of the total system is $\rho_{A'ABB' } \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}^2 \otimes \mathcal{H}^2 \otimes \mathcal{H}^2 \otimes \mathcal{H}^2) $.

I want to find the amount of entanglement in the $A'A : BB'$ bi-partition. Is it correct to think of Alice's and Bob's total system as a system of two qudits so that the density operator of the total system is now given by $\rho_{\mathbf{AB}} \in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}^4 \otimes \mathcal{H}^4)$. Disregarding any structure of Alice's and Bob's subsystems,  as I am not interested in the amount of entanglement present in the subspaces of Alice and Bob individually? Where$\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ represents the set of linear operators on a Hilbert space \mathcal{H}.

What would be a suitable entanglement measure for the above scenario apart from Rungta's $I \  concurrence$ defined in https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.64.042315?

cross-posted at https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/26260/entanglement-across-a-bi-partition-of-a-many-particle-system

Comment: What does the $\in$ notation mean here? Density operators are not elements of the Hilbert space.

Comment: @Nobert Schuch my bad. Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes it is correct to think about qudits. In general, if you are looking at the amount of entanglement across a bipartition, you are ignoring the structure of whatever is within one side of the bipartition. Then you can apply any [bipartite entanglement measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement#Entanglement_measures) to your bipartite system (respectively combining each of $AA^\prime$ and $BB^\prime$ into one system) and you'll have succeeded.

The key is that YOU are the one choosing the bipartition. There may be entanglement properties across different bipartitions, there may be entanglement across all bipartitions, etc., and you get to choose what kind of entanglement you're quantifying when you inspect this system.